# Android Library - android-crop rotates captured images

Tags: android

I am using Android-Crop https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop in order to square crop the result from capturing an image with the camera onActivityResult. The problem is that for some reason this library seams to be rotating the images unpredictably.

The following is the Activity of the library that creates the output that I am handiling onActivityResult - [CropImageActivity](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/soundcloud/android/crop/CropImageActivity.java).

The result from the cropping is simply loaded with Picasso in an ImageView. The image file is temporary stored in **Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)** , this file is given as EXTRA_OUTPUT for the capturing of the image, then being cropped and then loaded in the ImageVIew.

The problem is that for some Android phones the images are rotated correctly, but for others they are not. Nexus 5 is ok, Xperia Z is not and so on...

I am looking for a simple way to make sure the images Are correctly rotated.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What makes you think that this is the fault of this library, rather than being the fault of the devices or the camera apps that you are using on them? Are you examining the EXIF headers to see if an orientation header is included?

Comment: When skipping the step with the cropping the images are with their proper orientation.

Comment: checkout [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle I found the answer. The  library is extracting the exif data from the MediaStore, but I am not storing my temp files there. There are two possible solutions that came to my mind. The first is to read the exif orientation before the cropping and set the orientation attribute after the cropping. The other way is to save your files into the media store.

```
CropUtil.copyExifRotation(CropUtil.getFromMediaUri(this, this.getContentResolver(), 
this.sourceUri), CropUtil.getFromMediaUri(this, this.getContentResolver(), this.saveUri));
        this.setResultUri(this.saveUri);
```

Comment: where i need to write this?

Comment: @Tara after you take the image

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop
It can rotate image.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [This cropping library](https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView) and it is working perfectly fine. Below are the steps which will work out.

1. Add "compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.7' " in your build.gradle(app) file
2. Create a global variable in your main class file from which you are calling camera intent like 
      **private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FOR_IMAGE_CROPPING = 65 ;**

   **public static final int REQUEST_CODE_FOR_OPENCAMERA = 300;**
3. onButton click listner of opening camera write below code

   ```
   // create file 
   File newfile = createFile();
   Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);
   String uriString = outputFileUri.toString();

   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
   context.startActivityForResult(intent, OPENCAMERA);
   ```
4. write below method for creating a file after a onCreate().

   ```
    private File createFile() {
   String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
   myDir = new File(root + File.separator + "YourFolderName");
   if (!myDir.exists())
       myDir.mkdirs();

   File newfile = new File(myDir, "IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".JPG");
   try {
       newfile.createNewFile();
   } catch (IOException e) {
   }
   return newfile;
   }
   ```
5. Get data on onActivityResult of camera intent like below.

   ```
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FOR_OPENCAMERA) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           try {
               uriStr = (Uri) data.getExtras().get("data");

               Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uriStr);

               if (bitmap != null) {

                   Intent gotoCropImage = new Intent(thisActivity, CropMyImageActivity.class);
                   gotoCropImage.setData(uriStr);
                   startActivityForResult(gotoCropImage, REQUEST_CODE_FOR_IMAGE_CROPPING);
               }

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
           // user cancelled Image capture
           DialogManager.showToast(thisActivity, getString(R.string.user_cancelled_image_capture));
       }
   }
   ```

> 6. Create new activity with name CropMyImageActivity.java and write below code

```
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.ImageButton;

  import com.isseiaoki.simplecropview.CropImageView;
  import com.isseiaoki.simplecropview.callback.CropCallback;
  import com.isseiaoki.simplecropview.callback.LoadCallback;
  import com.isseiaoki.simplecropview.callback.SaveCallback;
  import com.pioneer.parivaar.activities.BaseActivity;

  public class CropMyImageActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Uri mSourceUri = null;
private CropImageView mCropView;
private Bitmap.CompressFormat mCompressFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG;
private ImageButton rotateLeft, rotateRight, doneBtn, cancelBtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop_my_image);

    mCropView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.cropImageView);
    rotateLeft = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonRotateLeft);
    rotateRight = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonRotateRight);
    doneBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonDone);
    cancelBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);

    mSourceUri = getIntent().getData();

    rotateLeft.setOnClickListener(this);
    rotateRight.setOnClickListener(this);
    doneBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    // load image
    mCropView.setCropMode(CropImageView.CropMode.SQUARE);
    mCropView.load(mSourceUri)
            .useThumbnail(true)
            .execute(mLoadCallback);


}

private final LoadCallback mLoadCallback = new LoadCallback() {
    @Override public void onSuccess() {
    }

    @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
    }
};

private final CropCallback mCropCallback = new CropCallback() {
    @Override public void onSuccess(Bitmap cropped) {
        mCropView.save(cropped)
                .compressFormat(mCompressFormat)
                .execute(mSourceUri, mSaveCallback);
    }

    @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
    }
};
private final SaveCallback mSaveCallback = new SaveCallback() {
    @Override public void onSuccess(Uri outputUri) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setData(outputUri);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        finish();
    }

    @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
    }
};


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonRotateLeft:
            mCropView.rotateImage(CropImageView.RotateDegrees.ROTATE_M90D);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonRotateRight:
            mCropView.rotateImage(CropImageView.RotateDegrees.ROTATE_90D);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonDone:
            mCropView.crop(mSourceUri).execute(mCropCallback);
            break;

        case R.id.buttonCancel:
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
            break;
    }
}
}
```

> 7. Create an xml file with name activity_crop_my_image.xml like below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.isseiaoki.simplecropview.CropImageView
    android:id="@+id/cropImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin25"
    custom:scv_background_color="@color/windowBackground"
    custom:scv_crop_mode="fit_image"
    custom:scv_frame_color="@color/colorAccent"
    custom:scv_frame_stroke_weight="1dp"
    custom:scv_guide_color="@color/colorAccent"
    custom:scv_guide_show_mode="show_always"
    custom:scv_guide_stroke_weight="1dp"
    custom:scv_handle_color="@color/colorAccent"
    custom:scv_handle_show_mode="show_always"
    custom:scv_handle_size="14dp"
    custom:scv_min_frame_size="50dp"
    custom:scv_overlay_color="@color/overlay"
    custom:scv_touch_padding="8dp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin7"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin7"
    android:background="@color/black"
    />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/cropImageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/crop__ic_cancel" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonRotateLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin5"
            android:src="@drawable/rotate_left" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonRotateRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin5"
            android:src="@drawable/rotate_right" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/crop__ic_done" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> 8. OnActivity result of REQUEST_CODE_FOR_IMAGE_CROPPING write below code

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FOR_IMAGE_CROPPING ){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
            mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            Uri myUri = data.getData();
            mExecutor.submit(new LoadScaledImageTask(this, myUri, profileImage, calcImageSize()));
            imageTypedFile = new TypedFile("multipart/form-data", new File(myUri.toString().substring(7)));
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            DialogManager.showToast(BigFarmerActivity.this, getString(R.string.user_cancelled_image_cropping));
        }
    }
```